# Haskell: Output list of tuples as string output

Tags: string, list, function, haskell, tuples

I'm trying to get this list of tuples:

```
[(2,"a"), (1,"a"), (1,"b"), (1,"c"), (2,"dd")]
```

into this string output

```
a 1,2

b 1

c 1

dd 2
```

I assume I need to use the unzip and unlines functions. But I also saw some solutions using the show function which makes the integers strings. Any ideas?

Comment: You have some ideas how to proceed; do they work?  Please post what you have before asking for help on your homework.  But: what kind of list do you need to have before you can output `a 1,2`?  How would you build that list from that input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break the problem down into steps.  What you really want to do first is aggregate all the tuples that have the same string in the second position, so you'll have a function like

```
aggregate :: [(Int, String)] -> [([Int], String)]
```

So for your input list you would get the output

```
[([1, 2], "a"), ([1], "b"), ([1], "c"), ([2], "dd")]
```

Your hints are

```
aggregate items = someFunc (map (\(num, str) -> ([num], str)) items)
```

And take a look at `foldr`.  Before you ask a follow up question about `foldr`, there are probably hundreds of stackoverflow answers showing how to use it already, take some time to figure it out or it'll get closed immediately as a duplicate.

Then you need a function to convert a single tuple of this form into a single `String` for outputting:

```
prettyPrint :: ([Int], String) -> String
prettyPrint (nums, str) = str ++ " " ++ joinWithComma (map show nums)
```

Where you'll have to implement `joinWithComma` yourself.  Then you need to calculate this and print it for each item in your aggregated list, `mapM_` and `putStrLn` would be preferred, so your `main` might look like

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let inputList = [(2,"a"), (1,"a"), (1,"b"), (1,"c"), (2,"dd")]
    mapM_ (putStrLn . prettyPrint) (aggregate inputList)
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance here! So based off your 1st hint, the aggregate function (w/o someFunc) makes the first element in the tuple into a list. I assume I need to use find "someFunc" that will combine the list of integers in the 1st tuple spot if the 2nd tuple spot is the same. Is foldr apart of this process?

Comment: @shamu11 Correct, `someFunc` is what you'll need to implement.  The rest of that definitely is simply taking every `(n, str)` and turning it into `([n], str)`.  Folds are the Haskell way of doing loops that aggregate a value, and `foldr` is a good place to start.

Comment: @shamu, there is a convenience function, `intercalate`, that you may find helpful dealing with part of this answer.

Comment: Okay so I see how both intercalate and foldr could be very useful here. I think I'm close when I do this: 

let aggregate items = foldr (intercalate) $ (map (\(num, str) -> ([num], str)) items)

however I'm still getting a type error.

Answer (score 2):

If you have this list:

```
pairs = [ ("a", [1,2]), ("b", [1]), ("c", [1]), ("dd", [2]) ]
```

then you can get the desired output with:

```
putStrLn $ unlines [ x ++ " " ++ unwords (map show ys) | (x, ys) <- pairs ]
```

but you have to figure out how to get the `pairs` list first.

Answer (score 0):

Work step by step. You could start with the `groupBy` function:

```
groupBy (\x y-> (snd x)==(snd y)) [(2,"a"), (1,"a"), (1,"b"), (1,"c"), (2,"dd")]
```

gives you

```
[[(2,"a"),(1,"a")],[(1,"b")],[(1,"c")],[(2,"dd")]]
```

The next step would be "totalling" the inner lists, `map` and `foldL` (and depending on your requirements maybe `sortBy`) should be helpful. If you have this, constructing the output is trivial (using `show`, as you already mentioned).